# Data Binding Combobox to Textbox

Tags: c#, wpf

I've been working with my program about books.It works like putting some information about the book and when done it is added in the list.
but when I pick a content in the combobox ( example 03 ) it will bind into my textbox as " System.Windows.Controls.ComboBoxItem: 03 " 
I just cant figure out how to make it 3 and remove the system.windows.etc 
Here is my code btw

```
<TextBox Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="3" Name="monthp" Margin="1" Text="{Binding book_datepublishedmonth,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />  
<ComboBox Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="3" Name="monthcombo" Margin="1" SelectedItem="{Binding Text , ElementName=monthp }"  >
<ComboBoxItem Content="01" />
<ComboBoxItem Content="02" /> 
<ComboBoxItem Content="03" />
</ComboBox>
```

When I run my code i really dont know why it has System.Windows.Controls.ComboBoxItem in the textbox. Is there something im missing?

Thanks in advance for pointing it out :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Explanation:**

*You are comparing/binding a string (monthp **TextBox.Text** Binding) with a **ComboBoxItem**.*

*You want to compare/bind the **ComboBoxItem.Content** with monthp **TextBox.Text***

You have to do two changes on your ComboBox:

> Add **SelectedValuePath="Content"**
>
> And change:
>
> **SelectedItem="{Binding Text, ElementName=monthp}"**
>
> To:
>
> **SelectedValue="{Binding Text, ElementName=monthp}"**

**Your code will be:**

```
<TextBox Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="3" Name="monthp" Margin="1" Text="{Binding book_datepublishedmonth, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
<ComboBox Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="3" Name="monthcombo" Margin="1" SelectedValuePath="Content" SelectedValue="{Binding Text, ElementName=monthp}"  >
    <ComboBoxItem Content="01" />
    <ComboBoxItem Content="02" />
    <ComboBoxItem Content="03" />
</ComboBox>
```

Comment: oh i see it was this easy all this time ! you save me there bro. thanks